# Regular pumping lemma proving L={Am+n Bm C2n} is not regular

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory, pumping-lemma

I wanted to prove that this language is not regular L={Am+n Bm C2n} so this is what i did :

Let m be the critical length of L and length |W|>/m

and i picked W=A3m Bm C2m

then from the pumping lemma i got: W=A3m Bm C2m with lengths |YZ|<\m, |Y|>/1

thus: y=Bk, 1\

from the pumping lemma: YZiX∈L   i=0,1,2,3...

thus: YZ0X=ZX∈L

thus: A3m Bk-m C2m ∉ L
     L={Am+n Bm C2n} We have here a contradiction therefore the language is not regular. IS THIS RIGHT ? or CAN YOU SHOW ME THE CORRECT SOLUTION please :D

Comment: Thus: y=Bk, 1\<k\<m*

Comment: This question is better suited to Computer Science SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com